# Unhandled exception in Adobe Reader while passing a search parameter in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, process

I'm writing a WinForms application and there's a method to search text strings into an array of pdf files. When the given text is found, the method should open the proper file, highlighting said text.

I followed the specifics found in the [Parameters for Opening PDF Files](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf) document, and this is the part of the code where I call the reader:

```
string arg = "/A search=\"" + parametri.testoDaRicercare + "\" \"" + file + "\"";
Process.Start("AcroRd32.exe", arg);
```

where `parametri.testoDaRicercare` is the string with the given text and `file` is the path to the pdf file.

Now, it works flawlessly with Adobe Reader XI, while I am given this error using Adobe Reader DC:

> Unhandled exception in 0x61D6796F (AcroRd32.exe) in AcroRd32.exe:
>   0xC0000005: access violation while reading the path 0x000002C0. An Exception occurred.

By the way I don't know whether it's a simple Adobe+Win10 issue or whatever, because if I set the parameters to open the pdf at a certain page it works fine on both machines.

```
string arg = "/A \"page=" + pagina + "\" \"" + file + "\"";
Process.Start("AcroRd32.exe", arg);
```

Comment: "You can search only for single words." This sentence means that each word sepparated by space will be searched individually. Per example, if you have "I am god" as the PDF content and you search "I god" the result will include both words, "I" and "god", you can't expect to treat the words as a single phrase.

Comment: @Gusman ok thanks. That doesn't explain the error I'm given on Win7 when searching for two words though, because performing a multiple words search is still perfectly legal.

Comment: No, that's why I didn't added it as answer, just wanted to help the bit I can :)

Comment: Hmm, im seeing something, your parameters string is wrong, it has some extra `\"`, the resulting string would be `/A "search="word1 word2"" "file"` and it should be `/A search="word1 word2" "file"`, I think that is the source of all your problems

Comment: @Gusman thanks. Your hint were right, it runs smooth on Win7 now, but the unhandled exception on Win10 remains.